# Azure API Manager - developer access

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a multi-application environment with api manager installed in each.

I want to enable cert authentication for our front-end systems, but I also want to enable developers to be able test the backend APIs through the API manager easily.

What would be the appropriate practice for allowing this? And then as well so I could provision this configuration between environemnts such that developer is disabled in our dev/qa environments? Looking for some best practice/advice.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using two products. One would enforce certificate authentication (via policy) and be available is all environments.

Second can use regular subscription keys to authenticate developers and be enabled only in Dev instance.

Comment: How could I best ensure the developer product never gets enabled in Production? I was planning to use the git configuration to deploy between environments but that appears to deploy all product configuration as well.

Comment: There is no built-in way to forcefully disable a product like that. You could try making it a step in configuration migration to disable one new configuration is deployed. Or you could place a conditional statement in dev product policy, that would deny request if request hostname does not match one used in dev environment.